# Using JqueryUI dropdown menu to show individual divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying out an alternative solution to issue I have been have with showing/hiding individual divs.

I am trying to use the JQUERY UI dropdown menu as a solution the dropdown menu menu works but my click functions are not.

Basically the all divs are hidden onLoad except for chartdiv1, as the user click the menu items then the other divs will show as needed. Your help is greatly appreciated.

my js fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/Jason1975/qtdojq2g/

HTML

```
<body onLoad="hide()">

<ul id="menu"> 
<li><a id="1">Unit Price</a></li>
<li>Unit Price in Alternative Currency
<ul>
<li><a id="2">GSO_EURO</a></li>      
<li><a id="3">GSO_GBP</a></li>
<li><a id="4">GSO_ZAR</a></li>    
</ul>  
</li>
<li>Unit Price Performance over period
<ul>
<li><a id="5">GSO_USD</a></li>
<li><a id="6">GSO_EURO</a></li>      
<li><a id="7">GSO_GBP</a></li>
<li><a id="8">GSO_ZAR</a></li>    
</ul>  
</li>
</ul>  

<br /><br />
    <!-- Chart Divs -->
    <!-- Chartdiv1 - Unit Price in US Dollars -->
    <div id="chartdiv1" style="width:100%; height:250px; background: #CCC"">CHARTDIV1 - USD CURRENCY</div><br />
    <!-- End Chartdiv1 -->
    <!-- Chartdiv2 - EURO Currency -->
    <div id="chartdiv2" style="width:100%; height:250px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV2 - EURO CURRENCY</div><br />
    <!-- End Chartdiv2 -->
    <!-- Chartdiv3 - GBP Currency -->
    <div id="chartdiv3" style="width:100%; height:250px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV3 - GBP CURRENCY</div><br />
    <!-- End Chartdiv3 -->
    <!-- Chartdiv4 - ZAR Currency -->
    <div id="chartdiv4" style="width:100%; height:250px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV4 -  ZAR CURRENCY</div><br />
    <!-- End Chartdiv3 -->
    <!-- Chartdiv5 - USD Unit Price Perfomance over a Period -->
    <div id="chartdiv5" style="width:100%; height:250px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV5 - USD PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div><br />
    <!-- End Chartdiv5 -->
    <!-- Chartdiv6 - EURO Unit Price Perfomance over a Period -->
    <div id="chartdiv6" style="width:100%; height:250px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV6 - EURO PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div><br />
    <!-- End Chartdiv6 -->
    <!-- Chartdiv7 - GBP Unit Price Perfomance over a Period -->
    <div id="chartdiv7" style="width:100%; height:250px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV7 - GBP PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div><br />
    <!-- End Chartdiv7 -->
    <!-- Chartdiv8 - ZAR Unit Price Perfomance over a Period -->
    <div id="chartdiv8" style="width:100%; height:250px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV8 - ZAR PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div><br />
    <!-- End Chartdiv8 -->

    <br>
```

THE JQUERY

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    hide();
    $( '#a#1').click( function() {
        var $select = $( this );
        if ( $select ) {
        $( 'div#chartdiv1' ).show();
        } else {
            $( 'div#chartdiv1' ).hide();
        }
        });
        $( 'a#2' ).click( function() {
        var $select = $( this );
        if ( $select ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv2' ).show();
        } else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv2' ).hide();
        }
        });
    $( 'a#3' ).click( function() {
        var $select = $( this );
        if ( $select ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv3' ).show();
        }  else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv3' ).hide();
        }
    });
    $( 'a#4' ).click( function() {
        var $select = $( this );
        if ( $select ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv4' ).show();
        }  else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv4' ).hide();
        }
    });
    $( 'a#5' ).click( function() {
        var $select = $( this );
        if ( $select ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv5' ).show();
        }  else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv5' ).hide();
        }
    });
    $( 'a#6' ).click( function() {
        var $select = $( this );
        if ( $select ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv6' ).show();
        }  else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv6' ).hide();
        }
    });
    $( 'a#7' ).click( function() {
        var $select = $( this );
        if ( $select ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv7' ).show();
        }  else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv7' ).hide();
        }
    });
    $( 'a#8'  ).click( function() {
        var $select = $( this );
        if ( $select ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv8' ).show();
        }  else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv8' ).hide();
        }
    });
    });
    function hide() {
    var show = ['chartdiv1'];
    for ( var i = 0; i < show.length; ++i ) 
    document.getElementById(show[i]).style.display = "block";
    var hide = ['chartdiv2','chartdiv3','chartdiv4','chartdiv5','chartdiv6','chartdiv7','chartdiv8','hidden','hidden2','currency','currency2'];
    for ( var i = 0; i < hide.length; ++i ) 
    document.getElementById(hide[i]).style.display = "none";
    }
    //END OF ALL THE CHART ITEMS
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what for I have rewritten code as well, but nevertheless.

- `<a>` `id` is replaced with `data-id`, which has `id` of target element.
- target `<div>`s styles are placed in CSS `chartdiv` class styles, including hiding by default.
- single `click` event handler is added to `<a>`s inside `<ul id="menu">`.
- target `<div>`s have additional `js-chartdiv` class for hide/show handling.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtdojq2g/3/).

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.js-chartdiv:first').show();

    $('#menu a').on('click', function()
    {
        $('.js-chartdiv:visible').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).data('id')).show();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a data-id="chartdiv1">Unit Price</a>
    </li>
    <li>Unit Price in Alternative Currency
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a data-id="chartdiv2">GSO_EURO</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-id="chartdiv3">GSO_GBP</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-id="chartdiv4">GSO_ZAR</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Unit Price Performance over period
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a data-id="chartdiv5">GSO_USD</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-id="chartdiv6">GSO_EURO</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-id="chartdiv7">GSO_GBP</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-id="chartdiv8">GSO_ZAR</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<br /><br />
<div id="chartdiv1" class="chartdiv js-chartdiv">CHARTDIV1 - USD CURRENCY</div>
<div id="chartdiv2" class="chartdiv js-chartdiv">CHARTDIV2 - EURO CURRENCY</div>
<div id="chartdiv3" class="chartdiv js-chartdiv">CHARTDIV3 - GBP CURRENCY</div>
<div id="chartdiv4" class="chartdiv js-chartdiv">CHARTDIV4 - ZAR CURRENCY</div>
<div id="chartdiv5" class="chartdiv js-chartdiv">CHARTDIV5 - USD PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div>
<div id="chartdiv6" class="chartdiv js-chartdiv">CHARTDIV6 - EURO PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div>
<div id="chartdiv7" class="chartdiv js-chartdiv">CHARTDIV7 - GBP PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div>
<div id="chartdiv8" class="chartdiv js-chartdiv">CHARTDIV8 - ZAR PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-menu
{
    width: 250px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.chartdiv
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background: #CCC;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See try to reuse the code this is script for all you need

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.chart').hide();
            $( 'div#chartdiv1' ).show();
            $('.showchart').click( function() {
                $('.chart').hide();
                $('#' + $(this).attr('data-chart')).show();
            });
        });
```

now 2 changes in html your link should be like

`<a class="showchart" data-chart="chartdiv1">Unit Price</a>` we have added class and data-chart attribute

now in chart div

`<div id="chartdiv1" class="chart" style="width:100%; height:250px; background: #CCC">`

add class **chart**

and try this

let me know this works for you or not ?

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answeer, I have implemented it as per suggestion it is not working, I will put together js fiddle maybe I have done something wrong. a question should would I not change .showchart on each link i.e .showchart1,2, 3............. does not make sense though a a class can be used more than once on a document

Comment: as per CSS **class** can be used N number of times where as **id** can be used once.

Comment: @RanaSoyab well, you can add your code to fiddle as well. Both to test your code and to show it as an example.

Comment: @RanaSoyab I hope you noticed that current shown block moves up-down because of all these `<br/>`? It looks annoying :)

Comment: simple dear try to remove br and check

Comment: Thanks and just Njoy coding :)